# How to convert double[][] to be parcelable

Tags: android, collections, parcelable

I have this:

```
public double[][] mRoute;
```

and I need to have it be `Parcelable`, but I am not certain of the best way to do this.

It appears that turning it into a `List` and then writing that isn't the right approach.

**UPDATE:**

This is what compiled from @yuku's answer.

```
    out.writeInt(mRoute.length); // store the length
    for (int i = 0; i < mRoute.length; i++) {
        out.writeInt(mRoute[i].length);
        out.writeDoubleArray(mRoute[i]);
    }
    mRoute = new double[in.readInt()][]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < mRoute.length; i++) {
         mRoute[i] = new double[in.readInt()];
         in.readDoubleArray(mRoute[i]);
    }
```

I haven't tried it, just got it to compile, which is a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a double[][] a Parcelable, but you can create a class that implements Parcelable and contains that double[][].

on writeToParcel(Parcel dest), do:

```
dest.writeInt(mRoute.length); // store the length
for (int i = 0; i < mRoute.length; i++) {
    dest.writeDoubleArray(mRoute[i]);
}
```

on readFromParcel(Parcel in), do:

```
mRoute = new double[][in.readInt()]; 
for (int i = 0; i < mRoute.length; i++) {
    mRoute[i] = in.readDoubleArray();
}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't think about this approach.  I am embarrassed I didn't, but it is such a simple solution.  Thank you. I will try it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) myself, but after reading the JavaDoc I think this will generally work:

1. Create a class `Foo implements Parcelable` that wraps a `double[]`, so you can use
   [`Parcel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html)`#[`[`create`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#createDoubleArray%28%29)`|`[`write`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeDoubleArray%28double%5B%5D%29)`]doubleArray()`, and then
2. Create a class `Bar implements Parcelable` which wraps a `Foo[]`, so you can use
   [`Parcel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html)`#[`[`create`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#createTypedArray%28android.os.Parcelable.Creator%3CT%3E%29)`|`[`write`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeTypedArray%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29)`]TypedArray()`

<sub>(Sorry, this is a bit long for a comment, I'm happy to delete if it's not useful.)</sub>

---

Like this (compiled but not tested, no `@Overrides`, *caveat emptor* and whot):

```
public class Foo implements Parcelable {
    private double[] mData;

    // Not really sure what bitmask to use for a double[]...
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeDoubleArray(mData);
    }

    public static final Creator<Foo> CREATOR = new Creator<Foo>() {

        public Foo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Foo(in);
        }

        public Foo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Foo[size];
        }
    };

    private Foo(Parcel in) {
        mData = in.createDoubleArray();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Bar implements Parcelable {
    private Foo[] mData;

    // Same as above
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeTypedArray(mData, 0);
    }

    public static final Creator<Bar> CREATOR = new Creator<Bar>() {

        public Bar createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Bar(in);
        }

        public Bar[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Bar[size];
        }
    };

    private Bar(Parcel in) {
        mData = in.createTypedArray(Foo.CREATOR);
    }
}
```